# Globally assigned variable is not displaying

Tags: node.js, pug

I am loading in an array of data, assigning each piece of the array to a global variable and then attempting to display it. For some reason I am not getting a value displayed for #{alibaba}.

```
script(type='text/javascript', src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")
    body
      script(type='text/javascript').
        var microsoft;
        var amazon;
        var apple;
        var mcdonalds;
        var berkshire;
        var alibaba;
        $.getJSON('../json', function(data) {
            microsoft = data[0];
            amazon = data[1];
            apple = data[2];
            mcdonalds = data[3];
            berkshire = data[4];
            alibaba = data[5];
        });
      p Alibaba Stock Price Is: #{alibaba}
```

Here is the array I am loading in from ../json

```
[
    "49.87",
    "93.74",
    "145.48",
    "659.59",
    "126.49",
    "76.94"
]
```

Comment: Javascript execution is asynchronous. The callback you pass to $.getJSON is executed at a future time when the data arrives from the server; thus you are printing earlier than the data is received. Try printing inside the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
script(type='text/javascript', src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")
    body
      script(type='text/javascript').
        var microsoft;
        var amazon;
        var apple;
        var mcdonalds;
        var berkshire;
        var alibaba;
        $.getJSON('../json', function(data) {
            microsoft = data[0];
            amazon = data[1];
            apple = data[2];
            mcdonalds = data[3];
            berkshire = data[4];
            alibaba = data[5];

            // when json is loaded we place data into tag span
            $("#alibaba").text(alibaba);
        });
      p Alibaba Stock Price Is: 
        span#alibaba
```